# Request info from each product by using requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, xml-parsing

Whenever I try to get a request from each product url (`product_info`)
And I try to show the status code of my request it shows 414 which means there are too many requests.
I have tried to split the product info variable by the split function but it doesn't display information as it supposed to.

```py
import requests as r
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
def get_ProductData():
    url = 'https://shopnicekicks.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=1169123841&to=7106802188493'
    data = r.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text,'xml')
    title = soup.findAll('title')
    for titles in title:
        titles.decompose()
        info = ''.join(soup.stripped_strings)
        product_info = info + '/products.json'
        response = r.get(product_info,params=product_info)
        print(response.status_code)

# Run the function
get_ProductData()
```

Comment: Can you include the `r.text` of the failed request?

Comment: Try to use custom `User-Agent` header or *(even better)* switch it every request.

Comment: `HTTP 414` is [URI Too Long](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/414), not [429 Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429). Check the value of `product_info`.

Comment: I can't switch the user-agent every time because I'm getting the product name from the website and adding '.json'

Comment: When I try too look the text from the info variable so I can get a URL from bunch URL it displays gibberish

Comment: @Yarik, that makes no sense, you can set different headers for every request

Comment: Ok then can you Pls  give me an example how you would have done it

Comment: I get what ur saying but the problem is when I print that product info I get alot of products urls in a list form what I want to do is to get each of products url from every product . I tried using a for loop but its just prints out gibberish.

Comment: @Yarik [this tutorial](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-fake-and-rotate-user-agents-using-python-3/) gives a pretty good explanation of user agents as well as  examples of how to fake them and then rotate through them

Comment: @Yarik, something like [this](https://t.ly/JtpD).

Answer (score 0):

You were not getting the urls right. There are 2 url addresses per product one is within loc tag and another within image:loc tag. If you get them right you can get what you need. Here is the code that gets both urls and tests for response. I exit the loop after 4 passes:

```py
import requests as r
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup

def get_ProductData():
    url = 'https://shopnicekicks.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=1169123841&to=7106802188493'
    data = r.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text,'xml')
    
    urls = soup.findAll('url')
    
    i = -1
    for url in urls:
        i += 1
        if i > 4:
            break
        img_loc = url.find('loc')
        img_title = url.find('title')
        try:
            print(str(i) + ' * ' + img_title.text)
            response = r.get(url.loc.text)
            print('response for loc: ' + url.loc.text + ' is ' + str(response.status_code))

            response = r.get(img_loc.text)
            print('response for image:loc: ' + img_loc.text + ' is ' + str(response.status_code))
            print('____________________________________________________')
        except:
            pass
# Run the function
get_ProductData()
'''
    R e s u l t :
1 * Stampd LA Logo Tee Mens T-Shirt - Grey
response for loc: https://shopnicekicks.com/products/puma-568944-01-stampd-la-logo-tee-mens-t-shirt-grey is 200
response for image:loc: https://shopnicekicks.com/products/puma-568944-01-stampd-la-logo-tee-mens-t-shirt-grey is 200
____________________________________________________
2 * Stampd Print Tee Mens T-Shirt - Black
response for loc: https://shopnicekicks.com/products/puma-568946-02-stampd-print-tee-mens-t-shirt-black is 200
response for image:loc: https://shopnicekicks.com/products/puma-568946-02-stampd-print-tee-mens-t-shirt-black is 200
____________________________________________________
3 * Ethnic Woven Long Sleeve Shirt - White
response for loc: https://shopnicekicks.com/products/stussy-111817-wht-st-ssy-ethnic-woven-long-sleeve-shirt-white is 200
response for image:loc: https://shopnicekicks.com/products/stussy-111817-wht-st-ssy-ethnic-woven-long-sleeve-shirt-white is 200
____________________________________________________
4 * F.C. Woven N98 - Midnight Navy/Deep Royal Blue
response for loc: https://shopnicekicks.com/products/nike-687952-410-nike-f-c-woven-n98-midnight-navy-deep-royal-blue is 200
response for image:loc: https://shopnicekicks.com/products/nike-687952-410-nike-f-c-woven-n98-midnight-navy-deep-royal-blue is 200
____________________________________________________
'''
```

Regards...